# VideoView clicklistener not possible

Tags: android

I'm trying to pause the video when the user clicks on it but looks like the setOnClickListenter isn't called.

I've used setOnClickListener(this) for all my other views and they work. Can somebody shed some light on why this isn't working with a VideoView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here, you need to use

```
    onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html